# Best way to generate an svg from this png

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, png, bitmap

Attempting to get a high quality image from the TensorBoard projector my last hope lies in producing a svg from a screenshot. My attempts to create an svg in inkscape ended up relatively blurry and I am hoping to get some advice on the right settings or possibly another method. Size does not matter. I just want a sharp, scalable image.

[Picture updated]

[image]

Comment: Why dont you just iterate the dataset? And draw the circles yourself.

Comment: A "high quality" vector version of this image would make a rectangle for each pixel. Mission accomplished; particularly since "size does not matter". You are *way* better off working from the original dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Multilevel neural net math packages are slightly beyond the capablities of most of us - otherwise I would run it and let it write the answer.

Seriously: Obviously you can create a set of xy coordinates from your data. Check the following extension of Inkscape: cartesianPlotData2D

It's  available here: https://inkscape.org/sk/~fsmMLK/resources/

There are other tools, too.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorboard projector seems to use Three.js which has an [SVG rendering backend](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/renderers/SVGRenderer). If you are experienced with javascript and web programming you might be able to get SVG output by replacing the Three.js constructor `THREE.WebGLRenderer()` with `THREE.SVGRenderer()`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually getting better results from Inkscape's tracing function, I rarely use Vector Magic, but it's a handy item to have, although pricey.

I popped an image copy of your dots into the program and got a surprisingly good result, selecting the "photograph" option as the source.

It's available for your perusal for a limited time:
[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1U-1OvpQkx-cPCvigsb4vgdR3JTtb6bTA)

Please advise when you have retrieved it, as I intend to remove it when it serves the purpose.